# Bitlocker storage drive suddenly shows as "Uninitialized"

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd, bitlocker

One of my storage drives (a Samsung 840 Pro SSD) suddenly stopped showing up in Windows Explorer. I went to disk management (I am on W10 Pro) and it shows the drive as "Uninitialized". The drive is not detected at all by other disk management software such as TestDisk, Parted Magic, EaseUS, or Partition Wizard, or by cloning software such as Clonezilla.

I have also tried plugging it into a different SATA port and using a different SATA and power cable (switched from one of my other drives which is working fine), and I also tried accessing it from my laptop, but there was no change.

It also takes an extraordinarily long time for the computer to boot up (both in getting through the BIOS, plus it hangs for about 30 seconds after the W10 login screen shows up) when the drive is plugged in, but everything boots up instantly as normal when the drive is disconnected. However, the drive does not show up at all in the BIOS boot order, so there is nothing for me to change there.

The drive seems to be simply dead in some way, although it would be quite a random occurrence; it is also worth noting that I had the same problem with another SSD a while ago (a Crucial MX100) which I encrypted with Bitlocker, and after about 6 months (same time frame for this one too) it started not showing up in Windows in exactly the same way, except if I rebooted enough times eventually it would show up again (but that has not worked so far this time). With the Crucial drive, after a few times of it disappearing, I reformatted that drive and now use it for normal unencrypted data, and the drive has been working perfectly ever since, which was about a year ago. So I am inclined to think this is a software or data/config corruption issue of some sort, but of what sort I have no clue.

Critical data I have backups of, though there are some personal files it would be annoying to lose but not the end of the world if there is simply no solution. Just wanted to see if there are any other ideas or insights though, because I have never seen behavior quite like this and am really stumped as to what has happened.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware failure.  " I reformatted that drive and now use it for normal unencrypted data, and the drive has been working perfectly ever since, which was about a year ago." - *Once you did this you made data recovery impossible.*

Comment: That was a different drive that had a similar failure in the past. The data on that drive was removed before I formatted it. The Samsung drive that has failed now has not been reformatted yet or had any other operations performed on it so far.

Comment: You should edit your question to indicate that fact.  I read your question and I made the incorrect conclusion.  If the drive in question, has nothing to do with your current problem, I wouldn't even mention it to be honest.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it already clearly stated. "it is also worth noting that I had the same problem with another SSD a while ago (a Crucial MX100) ... With the Crucial drive, after a few times of it disappearing, I reformatted that drive and now use it for normal unencrypted data, and the drive has been working perfectly ever since". It does have to do with the current problem because that drive had the exact same issue, and yet continues to work fine after a reformat. So, although this drive shows the exact same symptoms, which appear to be hardware failure, I wonder if that is really the case.

Comment: You really should clarify your question instead of submitting a comment.  Which is the reason I said in my last comment to edit your question.